# Turn off Hammer JS events in Angular 2 to allow scrolling

Tags: angular, hammer.js

I am using Hammer JS for swipeleft and swiperight events, but the user still needs to be able to scroll up and down.  I was able to capture the swipeup and swipedown events, but what I really want to do is disable them (and panup and pandown).  How would I do that inside of Angular 2?

Under Manager there is a method off that unbinds an event, I just don't know how to call this from within Angular 2.

[Manager off method doc](https://hammerjs.github.io/jsdoc/Manager.html#off)

Or is there another way to override Hammer JS to allow normal scrolling?

Answer (score 8):

These links pointed me in the right direction:

- https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-hammerjs-touch-gesture-in-angular-2#customize-hammerjs
- https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/1014
- http://hammerjs.github.io/touch-action/

In my module.ts I added the following:

```
import { HammerGestureConfig, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';

declare var Hammer: any;

export class MyHammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
    buildHammer(element: HTMLElement) {
        let mc = new Hammer(element, {
            touchAction: "pan-y",
        });
        return mc;
    }
}

@NgModule({
    providers: [
        { provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: MyHammerConfig }
    ]
})
```

Comment: @DoryZidon fwiw it solved it perfectly for my Angular 7 CLI Application. I just added the above code to my AppModule. Hope that helps!

Comment: Did you try it on a physical safari iphone ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create one .ts file in my case it is **hammer.config.ts** 
In that file put following code,

```
import { HammerGestureConfig } from '@angular/platform-browser';

declare var Hammer: any;

export class AppHammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
    buildHammer(element: HTMLElement) {
        let mc = new Hammer(element, {
            touchAction: "auto",
        });
        return mc;
    }
}
```

After that in your **app.module.ts** file put following object in providers,

```
{ provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: AppHammerConfig }
```

It will look like,

```
 providers: [
    //other_providers,
    { provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: AppHammerConfig }
  ]
```

Don't forget to import  HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG in app.module.ts like,

```
import { HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Also you need to import your created class AppHammerConfig from its location like,

```
import { AppHammerConfig } from '--path--/hammer.config';
```

This works for me.!

Answer (score 0):

In my angular 8 app I am using following solution:

```
npm install hammerjs --save
npm install  @types/hammerjs --save
```

and in my angular class file:

```js
    import {HammerGestureConfig } from '@angular/platform-browser';


    export class MyHammerGestureConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {

       // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
       buildHammer(element: HTMLElement) {
           return new Hammer(element, {
               touchAction: 'pan-y'
       });
    }

    }
```

and as described above from JEM

After that in your app.module.ts file put following object in providers,

```
  { provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: MyHammerConfig }
```